# Does accelerating blackhole grow in size due to constant infalling unruh radiation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, general-relativity, unruh-effect

Unruh effects stipulates that an accelerating observer will observe a thermal bath, like blackbody radiation, whereas an inertial observer would observe none. Now assume a constantly accelerating rocket creates a blackhole on board (blackhole large enough that its hawking radiation is less than Unruh radiation) -So the blackhole should grow bigger

However, from the frame of reference of a person at non accelerating frame - there is no Unruh radiation and blackhole is only accelerating in otherwise empty space -thus emitting hawking radiation and shrinking instead so it should not grow in size.

Only one of the above seems to be true at a given time

Am i missing something ? how do I resolve and find out the answer ?

Comment: This is simply an involved version of the [Paradox of radiation of charged particles in gravitational field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_radiation_of_charged_particles_in_a_gravitational_field).

Comment: Thanks @JeanbaptisteRoux but the situation does not involve any charged particles - Further, i radiation falling into the event horizon should be real effect and not frame dependent

Comment: Unruh effect *is* frame dependant.

Comment: Sticking a black hole into Rindler space and assuming Unruh's original prediction to still hold sounds quite naive to me.